# Which data structure to use as Stack with random position insertion ability?

Tags: data-structures

Card game, where used cards go back to the deck, but are not inserted of the bottom, but at a **random position within the 2nd half of the deck**.

Such as given a deck with cards `[c5, c6, c7, c8, c9]`
the next `pop` operation should return `c5`, and after `c5` is used, it should be reinserted into the deck within the 2nd half,
ie before `c8` OR after `c8` Or after `c9`

How would you design an efficient data structure for this deck?

Amount of cards is constant

Comment: The best I can think of is a linked list-based stack, but this is going to be O(n) for each pop (since a pop here is actually a pop+insert)

Comment: The pop will be O(1) as I can keep ref to the head, but insertion to the middle will be O(n)

Comment: Exactly, and here, since a pop will be a pop+insert, that's O(1)+O(n) :(

Comment: To further optimize insertion, he could keep a pointer to the middle of the stack, and move it forward when a pop is executed, then start the insertion lookup from that pointer. It would change insertion to O(n/2) which is still O(n), but technically a bit faster.

Answer (score 3):

If the number of cards is really always 52, then an array makes a fine data structure. Since the number of elements is constant, all operations are constant time.  Moving elements in consecutive memory locations is extremely fast in modern systems. You'll have a hard time doing better with a more sophisticated data structure.

If the number of cards can vary arbitrarily, I suggest a [an order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree). In such trees, each node tracks the number of nodes in the subtree of which it is the root.  This enables insertion and removal at any ordinal position.  Effectively, this gives you an array where insertion and removal are O(log n) it the tree is balanced.

Happily since you are re-inserting randomly, you get expected O(log n) performance "for free" if you initially create a balanced tree for the deck.  If you want worst case O(log n), you can make the tree self-balancing (red-black, AVL, etc.).

To deal from the top of the deck, remove position 0. To re-insert, pick a random number in 0-51, and insert at that ordinal position.

Comment: How is insertion into array random position is O(1)? Don't I have to move around the rest of the cards which are located in front of the inserted card? Popping is also quite tricky with an array.
(the amount of cards is constant)

Comment: The definition of big O is always with respect to some _variable_ describing input size. If the input size does not vary, then every operation is constant time. How is popping tricky? Move all the cards up by 1.

Comment: @Gene wouldn't the _variable_ be the array size? Just like it is when you sort an array.

Comment: If there are always 52 cards, the array size does not vary. For big O to make any sense you need to have a deck of arbitrary size.

Comment: You are right, and though it's O(1), I'm looking for an efficient solution with a constant array size, because shifting values within an array is a bit annoying, plus it's not regular poker cards, so the amount of cards is rather big

Comment: Note also that for n=52, you could easily go through a lot of trouble to implement a fancy data structure with O(log n) performance and have it work _slower_ than the array. Moving 51 ints stored in consecutive order with a modern processor is extremely fast.

Comment: You are right. It's more of a curiocity question. + I'm using it in a monte carlo simulation, so it happens on bigger amount of cards and being repeated way more times than just 51 moves